# Create table from XML - Parse out Attribute as Header, InnerXml as value

Tags: xml, powershell

I have lots of XML files which contain data I need.  I need to parse out an attribute as the column headers and the InnerXml as the values.  I can handle looping through the documents, but pulling the individual attribute and innerxml is throwing me

XML file Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<files>
    <file type="lcmContract" id="72187_fi20190000046444">
        <title>Bacon Cheeseburger</title>
        <field name="lcmHeaderGrp"></field>
        <field name="lcmHasNote">_image=custom/crmNote.gif</field>
        <field name="lcmSubject">Bacon Cheeseburgers are Good</field>
        <field name="lcmPrincipal">Frontline Rock</field>
        <field name="lcmClosingDate">@20190704</field>
        <field name="lcmAclList">
Royalties
LEGAL_DEPT
LegalExt
MktgRock
AllExceptRestricted
LegalTemp
LEGAL_DEPT_READ
lcmAdmin
CONTRACT-Administrator
</field>
    </file>
</files>
```

Table I'm trying to get to:

| title | lcmSubject | lcmPrincipal | lcmClosingDate | lcmAclList |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bacon Cheeseburger | Bacon Cheeseburgers are Good | Frontline Rock | @20190704 | Royalties,LEGAL_DEPT,LegalExt,MktgRock,AllExceptRestricted,LegalTemp,LEGAL_DEPT_READ,lcmAdmin,CONTRACT-Administrator |

I can the lists of data I'm expecting, but can't Pivot them into headers and values.  I also don't really NEED all the data, so if I can figure out how to limit the columns based on the Attribute Name that'd be helpful.

Some of the scripts I've used:

`[xml]$xmlFile = Get-Content -Path C:\Doc.xml`

`$xmlFile.files.file.ChildNodes | Select-Object -Expand Name`
This brings back column headers, but in a list view

`$xmlFile.files.file.ChildNodes | Select-Object -Expand InnerXml`
This brings back values, but in a list view

Comment: So, `Format-Table`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of extracting names and values separately, do a single pass over `ChildNodes` and store them in a `hashtable`. A hashtable can be converted to `PSCustomObject` which `Format-Table` accepts.

Filtering can be done using `Where-Object` on the `name` property, which works both for the `title` and the `field` elements (for the former it's the name of the element itself).

```bash
# Note: The following should be preferred over Get-Content which
#       doesn't respect XML encoding!
$docPath = 'C:\Doc.xml'
$xmlFile = [xml]::new(); $xmlFile.Load(( Convert-Path -LiteralPath $docPath ))

# Create an ordered hashtable as a precursor for a PSCustomObject
$ht = [ordered] @{}

# Process all ChildNodes
$xmlFile.files.file.ChildNodes |
    # Filter by Name property (which is either element name or Name attribute)
    Where-Object Name -match 'title|lcmSubject|lcmPrincipal|lcmClosingDate|lcmAclList' | 
    ForEach-Object {
        # Get element text, trim whitespace, replace any line breaks by comma.
        $value = $_.'#text'.Trim() -replace '\r?\n', ',' 

        # Add hashtable entry (associate name with value)
        $ht[ $_.Name ] = $value 
    }

# Convert hashtable to a PSCustomObject so Format-Table prints it as expected.
[PSCustomObject] $ht | Format-Table -Wrap
```

**Output:**

```
title              lcmSubject                   lcmPrincipal   lcmClosingDate lcmAclList
-----              ----------                   ------------   -------------- ----------
Bacon Cheeseburger Bacon Cheeseburgers are Good Frontline Rock @20190704      Royalties,LEGAL_DEPT,LegalExt,MktgRock,Al
                                                                              lExceptRestricted,LegalTemp,LEGAL_DEPT_RE
                                                                              AD,lcmAdmin,CONTRACT-Administrator
```

Comment: This worked beautifully - but now looping through multiple XML documents gives me the header each time - how do I fix that?

Comment: @baconfeltoon Move `Format-Table` from inside of loop to outside. E. g. `$xmlFiles | ForEach-Object { <# process XML file #>; [PSCustomObject] $ht  } | Format-Table -Wrap`

Comment: @baconfeltoon Feel free to post a new question with your coding attempt. Makes it easier than discussion in comments here.

Comment: Thanks here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75736469/getting-an-empty-pipe-error-when-trying-to-move-format-table-outside-of-loop)