# Getting an empty pipe error when trying to move format-table outside of loop

Tags: xml, powershell, formattable

Trying to loop this code through multiple XML docs listed in a CSV, and not sure where to move my Format-Table without getting the `An empty pipe element is not allowed` error.

```
$CSV = Import-Csv "C:\Users\Megan\Documents\EC_Export\AllDocs.csv"

foreach($LINE in $CSV)
    {
    $docPath = $LINE.filepath

# Note: The following should be preferred over Get-Content which
#       doesn't respect XML encoding!

$xmlFile = [xml]::new(); $xmlFile.Load(( Convert-Path -LiteralPath $docPath ))

# Create an ordered hashtable as a precursor for a PSCustomObject
$ht = [ordered] @{}

# Process all ChildNodes
$xmlFile.files.file.ChildNodes |
    # Filter by Name property (which is either element name or Name attribute) (Can only do 10 fields at a time this way)
    Where-Object Name -match 'title|lcmSubject|lcmPrincipal|lcmClosingDate|lcmAclList' | 
    ForEach-Object {
        # Get element text, trim whitespace, replace any line breaks by comma.
        $value = $_.'#text' #.Trim() -replace '\r?\n', ',' 

        # Add hashtable entry (associate name with value)
        $ht[ $_.Name ] = $value 
    }

# Convert hashtable to a PSCustomObject so Format-Table prints it as expected.
[PSCustomObject] $ht} | Format-Table -Wrap
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **[`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) is a *language statement* and as such (unfortunately) cannot directly participate *in a pipeline***; that is, in your case you cannot directly append `| FormatTable -Wrap` to it.

  - This limitation is rooted in the fundamentals of PowerShell grammar; see [GitHub issue #10967](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10967#issuecomment-561843650) for background information.
  - The **reason for the `An empty pipe element is not allowed` error** is that the `foreach` language statement is invariably considered a *complete* PowerShell statement, causing `| Format-Table -Wrap` to be considered the *next* statement - which breaks, given that you cannot *start* a statement with `|`, the [pipeline operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#pipeline-operator-).
- There are various **workarounds**:

  - To *stream* your language statement's output to the pipeline, enclose it in `& { ... }`, i.e. enclose it in a [script block (`{ ... }`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) that you invoke via `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-).
  - To *collect your language statement's output up front* before sending it to the pipeline (still object by object, enclose it in `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--)
  - In your simple case, switch from a `foreach` *statement* to the analogous [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet*.

    - Note that, unlike the `foreach` statement, the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet has no explicit iterator variable, and requires you to refer to the pipeline input object at hand via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_)
    - As an aside: Somewhat confusingly, `foreach` (in addition to `%`) also exists as an *alias* of `ForEach-Object`. It is the *syntactic context* that determines whether `foreach` refers to the cmdlet or to the language statement.

Here's a simplified version of a `ForEach-Object` solution:

```
$CSV | ForEach-Object {
  # Note the need to use of $_ to refer to the input object at hand
  $docPath = $_.filepath
  # ... 
} | Format-Table -Wrap
```

Comment: @baconfeltoon I would opt for `ForEach-Object` as well. Note that you don't even need to read the CSV file into a variable first. You can do `Import-Csv "C:\Users\Megan\Documents\EC_Export\AllDocs.csv" | ForEach-Object { … }` instead. This streamlines the code and saves memory when working with really large CSV files.